# C# GMapRoute null and I not draw route

Tags: c#, google-maps, routes

I'm using `Gmap.Net.WindowsForm` but `GMapRoute` is null and is not drawing routing, `GMapRoute` gives a NullReference error.

```
GMapOverlay routeshow = new GMapOverlay("yeni rotasyon");
end = new PointLatLng(37.790658, 28.014990);
first = new PointLatLng(37.790658, 29.014990);
//Rotasyon Belirleme
GDirections direction;
var route = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out direction, first, end, false, false, false, false, false);
GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "routes"); // error happens here
routeshow.Routes.Add(routes);
gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(routeshow);
gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(points, "routes")` needs points referring to its route, these points are of type `PointLatLng`. Fixing this would work.

```
        List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(37.790658, 28.014990));
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(37.790658, 29.014990));

        GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(points, "routes");
```

Every code would look like this.

```
        GMapOverlay routeshow = new GMapOverlay("yeni rotasyon");

        List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(37.790658, 28.014990));
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(37.790658, 29.014990));

        GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(points, "routes");
        routeshow.Routes.Add(routes);
        GMapControl.Overlays.Add(routeshow);
```

Comment: using your code i just see map and red cross on center. what is wrong? : provider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
            provider.ApiKey = "mysecretkey";
            gMapControl2.MapProvider = provider;
            List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng> {pos1, pos2};
            GMapOverlay routeshow = new GMapOverlay(points[0].ToString());
            GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(points, "routes");
            routeshow.Routes.Add(routes);
            gMapControl2.Overlays.Add(routeshow);

Comment: Your code is basically correct, maybe you just don't see the correct coordinate.

Comment: GMapControl.Position = new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575);
GMapControl.MinZoom = 3;
GMapControl.MaxZoom = 20;
GMapControl.Zoom = 17;

List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng> { new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575), new PointLatLng(48.863868, 2.321554) };